How to install a new wifi driver for a wifi adapter in ubuntu 20.04?
I bought a TP-Link Ax1800 Dual Band Wi-Fi 6 Wireless USB adapter archer Tx20U.
I saw online that I needed to install some drivers, specifically rtl8852au as they were not standard with the kernel for ubuntu 20.04
I have followed the steps here by larry finger but my wifi adapter is not working.
I have tried to add it to my ubuntu packages so I don't have to add it everytime a new kernel is updated but when I run sudo dkms status, it gives the error message rtl8852au/1.15.0.1, 6.8.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!).
This is the only error I got from following the steps in the link above. How do I get my adapter to work?/How do I ensure the built and installed modules are the same?
I am currently using a different tp-link wifi adapter to access the internet. In the code below Bus 001 Device 015: ID 35bc:0100 Realtek 802.11ac WLAN Adapter is the new adapter.
uname -a
Linux <REDACTED> 6.8.0-45-generic #45~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Sep 11 15:25:05 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 30fa:2031 INSTANT USB Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 2357:0109 TP-Link TL-WN823N v2/v3 [Realtek RTL8192EU]
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 35bc:0100 Realtek 802.11ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


sudo dkms status
rtl8852au/1.15.0.1, 6.8.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1, 5.15.0-122-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu/5.8.7.1, 6.8.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed

